# Reference kml field in url

Tags: href, kml

I have a kml with a href to be displayed as a clickable link in Google Maps.
Can the url be built using a field value? So if the field is called Heritage_Citation, can the url be something similar to

```
<![CDATA[<a href="https://portal.mornpen.vic.gov.au/wp-content/uploads/Heritage-Overlays/"<[%Heritage_Citation]>".pdf">Click to view this property's Heritage Study</a>]]>
```

or is this not possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this.

The format for variables in KML uses dollar sign and square brackets, so your example variable would look like this:

```
$[Heritage_Citation]
```

And your URL doesn't need quotes around the variable, so it can look like this:

```
<![CDATA[<a href="https://portal.mornpen.vic.gov.au/wp-content/uploads/Heritage-Overlays/$[Heritage_Citation].pdf">Click to view this property's Heritage Study</a>]]>
```

You may have this already, but just to be complete, the field and value need to be specified in the KML feature's ExtendedData section, something like this:

```
<ExtendedData>
  <Data name="Heritage_Citation">
    <value>my_variable_value</value>
  </Data>
</ExtendedData>
```

...or similar but different if using a typed data and a Schema based ExtendedData section. More details on all this in the documentation:
https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/extendeddata